# Uncaught TypeError: cadastro.fecharA is not a function at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Tags: javascript

estou com um problema com um script para fechar uma "Box".. segue os códigos abaixo:

cadastrar_associado.php

```
<form name="cadastro" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="acao" value="cadastro_simples" />
<div class="matricula">
    <label>Matrícula</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $idd; ?>" readonly>
</div>
<div class="nome">
    <label>Nome Completo</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
</div>
<div class="categoria">
    <label>Categoria</label>
    <select name="categoria" id="categoria">
        <option>Selecione a categoria</option>
        <option value="socio-efetivo">Sócio Efetivo</option>
        <option value="socio-contribuinte">Sócio Contribuinte</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="admissao">
    <label>Data de Admissão</label>
    <input type="date" name="admissao" id="admissao">
</div>
<div class="cadastrar" onClick="cadastro_simples();">CADASTRAR</div>
<div class="cancelar_cadastro" onclick="cadastro.fecharA();">CANCELAR</div>
</form>
```

script.js

```
var cadastro = {
associado: function(titulo, conteudo) {
    $('body').css({
        'margin': '0px',
        'padding': '0px'
    }).prepend('<div class="sombra_associado animated fadeIn"><div class="associado animated fadeInDown"><div class="topo"><div class="nome">SIGA<font style="font-size:10px;">V1.0</font></div><div class="titulo">' + titulo + '</div></div><div class="conteudo">' + conteudo + '</div></div></div>');
    $('.associado').fadeIn(200);
    $('.sombra_associado').fadeIn(200);
},
 fechar: function() {
    $('.associado').removeClass('animated fadeInDown').addClass('animated fadeOutUp');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.sombra_associado').removeClass('animated fadeIn').addClass('animated fadeOut');
        $('.sombra_associado').fadeOut(500);
        $('.associado').fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.sombra_associado').remove();
        }, 500);

    }, 300);
}
}
```

O que acontece... quando eu clico em um botão na minha index ele abre uma box para cadastrar um associado, porém quando clico para cancelar o cadastro, ele ao inves de fechar a box, ele me retorna o erro "Uncaught TypeError: cadastro.fecharA is not a function at HTMLDivElement.onclick ", o mesmo código porem com variveis diferntes, utilizei para outras funções semelhantes no site e todas funcionaram, somente esta causa problemas..

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta trocar *cadastro.fecharA* por *cadastro.fechar*.

O erro está no nome apenas, vendo que no **script.js** a variável cadastro é um objeto e possúi um atributo que é uma function chamada "fechar".

```
var cadastro = {fechar: function() {}}
```

Procede?

Comment: Continua o mesmo erro Thiago, o nome não faria diferença pois dentro da variavel cadastro, a outras funções de fechar como por exemplo, cadastro.fecharC, cadastro.fecharD

Comment: Ainda continua o erro ou ja encontrou a solução? É que você colou só uma parte do código, então deduzi que fosse a falta de um fecharA, mas veja se antes do fecharA não tem nenhum "}" fora do lugar.

Comment: Tudo certo Thiago